# Meaning of "*" and "/" in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, wikidata

I want to know the meaning of `*` and `/` in SPARQL.

If you check this [example](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23added%20before%202016-10%0A%0A%23defaultView%3ABubbleChart%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%28%3Fend%20-%20%3Fstart%20AS%20%3Fkk%29%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%09%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP361%2A%20wd%3AQ362%20.%0A%09%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2A%20wd%3AQ178561%20.%0A%09%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP580%20%3Fstart%20.%0A%09%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP582%20%3Fend%20.%0A%0A%09SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%0A%7D) from Wikidata, you will see that a `/` and a `*` are used in here:

```
?item wdt:P361* wd:Q362 .   
?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q178561 .
```

What are they for? Why are they used?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can find the meaning of those stars in the [`SPARQL 1.1 specs`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/), especially in section "[Property Path Syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#pp-language)"

Answer (score 1):

They are part of SPARQL 1.1 syntax which is called [property paths](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-property-paths/). They allow you to search for a specific path in the query.

For instance first basic graph pattern of yours (`wdt:P361*`) is serching for one or more occurance of the property `wdt:P361` associated with the resource `wd:Q362` - as long as time permits.

Or in the second one `/` allows you to search for a property `wdt:P31` which is followed by a `wdt:P279`. However, I reccomend you to start with trying shorter paths not to confront any execution timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

They are [Property Paths](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths). The first one selects subjects connected to the object `wd:Q362` by any number of `wdt:P361` properties. The second selects subject connected by `wdt:P31` followed by zero-or-more `wdt:P279` properties. There are some examples in the SPARQL 1.1 Query Language recommendation.